# Quiz in as3 error

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I've been trying to make quiz but i get bunch of errors that say:The public attribute can only be used inside a package.

```
    package 
{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Ilija
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            private var ButtonI:Loader = new Loader();
```

I get errors for all these vars
        private var ButtonI2:Loader = new Loader();
        private var ButtonI3:Loader = new Loader();
        private var Button1:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var Button2:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var Button3:Sprite = new Sprite();

```
    private var QuestionText:TextField = new TextField();
    private var A1Text:TextField = new TextField();
    private var A2Text:TextField = new TextField();
    private var A3Text:TextField = new TextField();
    private var pointText:TextField = new TextField();
    private var point:int = 0;

    private var _questions:Questions;
    public function Main():void
```

Comment: Two things can cause this.  **A:** you've prematurely closed the package/class with an extra `}` somewhere.  **B:** You're writing class code in your document code.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when you have { without a matching }

make sure you have an opening with closing curly brackets all over...